# Region isn't specified and can't be deduced from endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am getting issues when I implemented Custom Domain on AWS API and generated Android SDK ... now when I make authenticated calls to my API - SDK shows a error as follows:

`Region isn't specified and can't be deduced from endpoint`

What shall I do to remove this issue. I am sure its due to the custom domain implementation - because if I remove the custom domain mapping and then generate SDK - all calls are work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use a custom domain the region isn't part of the endpoint, therefore you have to provide the `region` to the `ApiClientFactory` explicitly.

Something like:

```
ApiClientFactory f = new ApiClientFactory()
.credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
.region("us-east-1") // or whatever region you have :) 
.endpoint("https://myendpoint");
```

Comment: Shouldnt be this done by the AWS SDK Generator ?? - I mean I should use the SDK as it generated - isnt it

Comment: See [this AWS Forum trace](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=231513) with a solution for a similar case.